# Send email with attachment whenever a particular table is updated

Tags: ms-access, macros

Would anyone know how to link a stand alone macro to automatically run against a table or query?

I am looking for an email with object attached to be sent each time the 'username table' is updated.

I have tried most other methods and none of them really do what I am looking so this is a last ditch effort.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Paula

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean "automatically run against a table or query"? If you mean table Data Macro like "Before Change", you can just call VBA public functions in any available action, for instance in `IF` action

Comment: @SergeyS. I am looking for an email with object attached to be sent each time the 'username table' is updated however the only way I can find of doing this is through creating a basic macro I have linked it to the 'username table' in the sense that it will now send an email but I cannot get it to work when the 'username table'  is updated.
The only way I could see round this would be to put it into the after insert function on the table itself but I cant seem to find a way to link this.

Comment: The username table is most likely updated via a form, no?  If so, can't you just run the macro in the OnClick event of whatever button you're pressing to write/update the username record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data macro for sending emails is a bad idea, it dramatically slows down table updating. Better way is sending email from form, which updates username table, use `AfterUpdate` form event.

If you still want to use data macro for calling any code and built-in SendEmail action in After Update table event is not enough, create public VBA  function, for instance `MySendObject` and call it from data macro using `If` action:

```
If MySendObject([ID]) Then
End If
```

or SetField:

```
SetField
 Name ResultsOfSending
 Value = MySendObject([ID])
```

Comment: If you are running event code in a form then it will "slow down ... updating" just like data macro code would. What is the significant difference that makes form code "better" than data macro code with respect to the "slowness" of updates?

Comment: If you update the table with data macro directly during maintenance or during other operations, which not require sending emails on each update, data macro unnecessary slows down update execution. Data macro works even slower than the same operation in query or recordset, I believe it's because it stored as XML, not p-code as compiled VBA or SQL code execution. Also data macro cannot be debugged during execution, error handling is worse than in VBA

Comment: Thanks, I ended up being able to get the after update function to work so I can send an email for specific changes being made. was unable to get it to send the object but I've got the main information I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the [SendEmail action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196780%28v=office.15%29.aspx) of an After Update [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) is insufficient for your needs then another option would be for that same data macro to write the pertinent information to a "queuing" table and then have a separate scheduled task run every few minutes (or so) to send the emails using a more full-featured mechanism like CDO (example [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/11/29/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-an-email-sent-using-cdo/)).